# How to create a fancy "add tag" system

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on my news system on my webpage, and I've come to the point where I want to include tags. What I want is to be able to submit tags that gets added to an array (hidden field) inside the form. I want to be able to add one and one tag which all gets added to an array and passed on to the verification page when the form is submitted. Much like the tag system here on stackoverflow. Either add one tag when seperated by ",", space or on return. Either one is fine by me.

The problem here isn't to get this working with php and mysql, that's easy. Presenting the tags is no problem either. All I need help for is the part where the tags get added. As I have little experience with Jquery, Ajax and Javascipt I'm unsure how to make this works.

The question is: What technology do I use to achieve this? Any code or similar tutorials are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery Tag-it http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/ it has a lot of options and can easily integrate with MySQL

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!